# Apex Audit log - Insert Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am creating a custom audit log as a process in the Apex application I have developed.

Below is the code I have used to log the actions by the user when they use the application. The LOGON_DT and LOGOFF_DT  will only need to be in a date format. However, QUERY_SEARCH_TIME will need the time.

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT_LOG
(USERNAME, ORDER_NO, ORDER_NAME, CUSTOMER_NAME, LOGON_DT, LOGOFF_DT, QUERY_SEARCH_TIME)
VALUES 
(:APP_USER, :P10_ORDER_NO, :P10_ORDER_NAME, :P10_CUSTOMER_NAME,  SYSDATE, SYSDATE, 
SYSDATE(HH24:MI:SS));
```

The above code works perfectly when *HH24:MI:SS* is taken off, and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this?

Any guidance will be great. Thank you!

Comment: You want to get only the time-component of `SYSDATE`? What is the datatype of the `QUERY_SEARCH_TIME` column?

Comment: Yes I only want the time-component of `SYSDATE`. The datatype of `QUERY_SEARCH_TIME` is `DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has it's own internal representation for a DATE datatype. You can't dictate its format in the way you are attempting.

It is common to apply a date format on retrieval, which you can do by applying the appropriate format mask as you convert to a string.

```
TO_CHAR(QUERY_SEARCH_TIME, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

A `DATE` column already captures a time component. It may not be necessary to cut it off. And if you do, you do not want a `DATE` column as such a column will always capture a whole date, and what would be the point if you want only time. 
To visualize the time component of a date you have to apply a format mask to it:
 `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS')`. If you want to capture just that, the time, then change the datatype of the column to a `VARCHAR2` type of sufficient length for the format mask you apply.

Read up on datetime datatypes here: [Oracle documentation on datetime types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm)
Read up on datetime format models here: [Oracle documentation on format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212)

Answer (score 0):

If you need time part of date only for output, you can use answer of Tom, but if you really need to store time part only, you can calculate it as

```
sysdate - trunc(sysdate)
```